# How to find true value in database?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I want to be able to print a receipt when something is true in the database. For example, clawcutting, it should print the line "Here are your receipt" + claw. But when I have ClawCutting true in the database, it still prints "Error". I do not really understand why it can not find it true in database?

```
public void DeleteFromService()
        {
            using (var db = new ApplicationDbContext())
            {
                double claw = 2.99;
                double hair = 3.99;
                double washing = 4.99;

                Console.WriteLine("Add your booking number on your service");
                Services s = new Services();
                s.Id = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                if(s.ClawCutting == true)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Here are your receipt" + claw);
                }
                else if(s.HairCut == true)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Here are your receipt" + hair);
                }
                else if (s.Washing == true)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Here are your receipt" + washing);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error");
                }
                db.Services.Remove(s);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Your code never loads anything from the database. `Service` is a new object and all its properties will have default values. If you want to load a specific item use `var s=db.Services.Find(id);` where `id` the primary key value of the item you want to load

Comment: According to the code, you are creating "s" and then trying to read the values of the flags; I don't see any function or action that populate the data of the object with the database.

Comment: Seems like you wished for to much magic to happen, that setting the `Id` property magically loads the data of from the database for the object with the given id. That's just to much to ask for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code never loads anything from the database. `Service` is a new object and all its properties will have default values. If you want to load a specific item use DbSet.Find where `id` the primary key value of the item you want to loadeg

```
var id=Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
var s=db.Services.Find(id);
if(s == null)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"No service with {id} was found");
    return;
}
```

These two methods will *delete* the Service from the database, so make sure you use them only if that's what you really want :

```
db.Services.Remove(s);
db.SaveChanges();
```